# Spring Tools Suite4

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

Iam unable to install a software[ Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development] in Spring Tools Suite4. Any help is appreciated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U5eI.png)

I clicked on help->Install New Software-> [ Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development]. But a problem occured.
Installing Software has encountered a problem. An error occured while collecting items to be installed.

Comment: The update site `https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/library/eclipse-dtp-1.14.100` seems to be broken. Does disabling this update site in the preferences _Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ fix your issue?

Comment: @howlger It does not give me any options for disabling in the install/Update window

Comment: "Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development" is an entire category. Perhaps you can deselect the Oracle SQL tools that are in the error message?

Comment: @nitind There is no specific option. I have to select that option and it contains [Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development]. There is no specific options that I can select or deselect.

Comment: What do you mean by _"install/Update window"_? You can disable or delete update sites in _Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ (on macOS _Preferences_ is in the application menu instead of in the _Window_ menu).

Comment: @howlger Yea your right I got it now when i deselected those sites it got installed.

Answer (score 1):

I double checked the overall ability to install additional plugins from that category into a fresh Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse 4.16.1.RELEASE installation and it installs just fine. So this doesn't seem to be a problem with the newly installed software from that category itself, but something else that interferes in the install process.

It looks like you installed additional plugins or server definitions from some Oracle update site before, which added a specific update site to the preferences that is now causing a problem.

You can go to `Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Update Sites` and remove that update site from the list of available update sites. That would help.

Another way to avoid this (probably) is to disable the option to `Contact all update sites during the install to find required software` in the `Install New Software` dialog. That should also prevent the install process from contacting that problematic update site.